# How to update / insert multiple documents based on condition in one query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following structure for 1 document :

```
{
    "uid": uid,
    "at": at,
    "url": url,
    "members": members
}
```

I would like to bulk create / or update the documents if they already exist based on their `uid` as i am passing many object like the above in one request.

I want something that looks like (in python) :

```
ids = []
for item in items:
  ids.append(item["uid"])
db.collection.update_many({"_id": {"$id": ids}}, {"$set": items}, upsert=True)
```

But will it update the correct documents according to the correct `ids` and insert the ones where `uid` doesn't exist ?

I would like to perform the `insert` OR `update` if the `object` exists or not it will either insert it or replace it based on the `uid`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of the server are you on?

Comment: I am on Atlas, using `Mongo 5.0.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to `upsert` a list of keys with a list of contents, e.g. (this is pseudocode, not valid MQL):

```js
keys = ['A','B'];
content = [{key:'A',name:'X',pos:1},{key:'B',name:'Y',pos:2}];
db.collection.updateMany(keys, {$set: content});
```

The `updateMany` function is designed to filter out a relatively small number of docs and apply a (mostly) constant update pattern, which is NOT the desired operation here.

It is possible to easily do this in a two step way:

1. Load your updates and potential inserts into a temp collection.
2. Use the `$merge` operator to overlay the material onto the target collection.

Consider this existing target collection `foo`:

```js
db.foo.insert([
    {uid: 0, at: "A", members: [1,2]},
    {uid: 1, at: "B", members: [1,2]},
    {uid: 2, at: "C", members: [1,2]},
    {uid: 3, at: "D", members: [1,2]}
]);
```

Assume we construct an array of items similar to the what the OP posted:

```js
var items = [
    {uid:1, at:"XX"},   // change
    {uid:3, at:"XX", members:[3,4]},  // change
    {uid:7, at:"Q", members:[3,4]},   // new
    {uid:8, at:"P", members:[3,4]}    // new
];
```

The following pipeline will merge these onto the target collection:

```js
db.TEMP1.drop(); // OK if does not exist

// Blast items into the TEMP1 collection.  You could use the bulk
// insert functions https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/ if you prefer,
// or in theory even use mongoimport outside of this script to bulk
// load material into TEMP1.
db.TEMP1.insert(items); 

c=db.TEMP1.aggregate([
    {$project: {_id:false}}, // must exclude _id to prevent conflict with target 'foo'
    {$merge: {
        into: "foo",  // ah HA!  
        on: [ "uid" ],
        whenMatched: "replace",
        whenNotMatched: "insert"
    }}
]);

db.foo.find();
{ "_id" : 0, "uid" : 0, "at" : "A", "members" : [ 1, 2 ] }  // unchanged
{ "_id" : 1, "uid" : 1, "at" : "XX" }     // modified and members gone
{ "_id" : 2, "uid" : 2, "at" : "C", "members" : [ 1, 2 ] }  // unchanged
{ "_id" : 3, "uid" : 3, "at" : "XX", "members" : [ 3, 4 ] }  // modified
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6228be517dec6ed6fa40cbe3"), "uid" : 7, "at" : "Q", "members" : [ 3, 4 ] }   // inserted
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6228be517dec6ed6fa40cbe4"), "uid" : 8, "at" : "P", "members" : [ 3, 4 ] }   // inserted
```

The caveat is a unique index must exist on `uid` in the target collection but that is probably what you would want to have anyway for such an operation to be reasonably performant.

This approach is more client-side data oriented, i.e. it assumes the client side is building up big, complete structures of data to either overlay or insert, as opposed to `update` which is more "surgical" in its ability to selectively touch as few fields as possible.

For quantitative comparison, 2 million docs sized roughly as above were loaded into `foo`.  A script that uses bulk operations loaded 50,000 items into `TEMP1` of which half had matching `uid` (for update) and half did not (for insert), followed by the running of the `$merge` script. On a MacBookPro w/16GB RAM and SSD disk and a v4.4.2 server, the times are

```js
1454 millis to insert 50013; 34396 ins/sec
7144 millis to merge; 7000 upd/sec
8598 total millis; 5816 ops/sec
```

If done in a simple loop:

```js
33452 millis for loop update; 1495 upd/sec
```

So the temp collection and `$merge` approach is nearly 4X faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer, i will try it right away. 
I have to use a temporary collection to make this work ? No other choice ?
I confirm that `uid` will be unique and there will be on index on it :)

Comment: For a bulk/batch approach where each `item` in the client array updates a *different* doc in the collection with *different* info, this is the only way.   You can of course do `db.foo.update()` in a **loop** and perform targeted updates one doc at a time but that's not what was asked.

Comment: exactly this is not i have asked (update in `loop`) so thanks again this is working !